# DRYing String spread across several classes

Tags: java, java-11

I have a Spring Boot app that makes calls to several end-points of a third-party app. "start_date" is passed as a request parameter in most of the calls. Today the string is inlined in classes that make the calls (there is one class for each third-party end-point). I would like to DRY the Strings.

If the calls were made from a single class, I could have a `private static final START_DATE = "start_date"` in that class. But the calls are in multiple classes. Is there a better solution than have a class dedicated to holding the values?

Note: Besides "start_date" there are 3 or 4 other request parameters that are also shared.

Comment: why not create a class to store these constant values `public`?

Comment: *Opinion:* Don't do this. The parameter names are not "shared", they just so happen to be named the same. That is a commendable consistency of naming, but it is not "sharing". Let the definition of each end point be in the code implementing the end point call. Moving some of the end point definition to another class just makes the code less clear to follow. --- Physically, there is no need. The JVM will merge them anyway in the string pool.

Comment: *Opinion continued:* What if one end point named the parameter `start_date`, another name it `startDate`, and yet another named it `startdate`, and that you have more than one of each spelling, i.e. triggering you to "share" them? How would you even name the string constants to keep the distinction clear? You can't. --- Don't start down this road, it leads to madness.

Comment: @Naman, Since the constant is now public, it can be used all over the codebase. There is nothing preventing programmers from using it indiscriminately in unrelated classes. Do you see this as an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply have a class to hold those values, but rather than using `private`, using `public`. As an example:

```
public class ApiConstants {
  public static final String START_DATE = "start_date";
}
```

You can then use the parameters:

```
ApiConstants.START_DATE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What are your thoughts on my comment to @Naman above?

Comment: I don't see it as a problem, but if you do, you can bundle it all together in the same package, and make access package-private. You do that by removing the `public` from the constant. If you were to create the `ApiConstants` class under the package `org.example.api`, every class on that package would have access to the constants, but nobody else on any other package. Would you prefer that?

Comment: It’s a good habit to add a constructor, `private ApiConstants() {}`, to emphasize the fact that this class should not be instantiated. Mind that if you don’t, the compiler will generate a `public` constructor.

Comment: Makes sense @Magd_Kudama. Thanks again.